# SQL queries for Total memory, Used Memory, Allocated Memory, Free Memory, Reserved Memory for the Oracle Server

Tags: oracle

I am requesting that please tell me how to get all(Total,Used,Allocated,Free,Reserved Memory details) these metrics for oracle server and I am getting confusing with SGA(System Global Area),PGA(Program or Process Global Area),UGA(User Global Area).

Answer (score 0):

These views will give you what you need:

```
v$sga_dynamic_components
v$SGA_DYNAMIC_FREE_MEMORY
v$shared_pool_reserved
v$SGASTAT
```

With regards to SGA, PGA and UGA - please tell us what is confusing you, as there is a lot of information about this on the internet.

Comment: Thank you @sandman . while calculating Total,Used,Allocated,Free,Reserved Memory details  should I add SGA,PGA,UGA  if yes then i am not getting how to do it, if no then how to build the queries. I need these memory details at server level not at processes level.

Comment: You should concentrate on SGA which is oracle's memory structure on the server. PGA and UGA are more for process memory usage.  The views I sent you are for SGA only.